# how to retrieve data using sqlite in html5

Tags: jquery, sqlite

I am trying an application in html 5 with back-end of Sq-lite. In that I have to retrieve  particular customer data by click their name and view data in another page. Here is my code.How to do that?

```
function renderData(row) {
    return "<a href ='viewlist.html' onclick='editRecord(" + row.ID +");'>" +         row.notepad_title  + "<span class='time_note'>" + row.notepad_date + "</span></a>";
}

function editRecord(id) { /* here i can get the clicked data id */
 var db = userlist.webdb.db;
 db.transaction(function(tx) {
 tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM u_notepad WHERE ID=?', [id], function(tx,results){
     for (var i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
        row = results.rows.item(i);
        editRecords(row.notepad_title,row.notepad_content);
     }
}); });   }
function editRecords(name,desc) {
des = $('#view_note');
des.html("");
des.html(f.html() + "<textarea  class='editarea' id='view_note'/>"+desc+"</textarea>");
}
```

Comment: And what would be wrong with this code?

Comment: In that editRecords() i can't access that textarea id